# ¿Cómo dibujar un circulo y un punto en un gráfico con Python y Maptplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gráficas

estuve haciendo un código en Python:

```
Point = plt.plot(CoordX, CoordY, marker="o", color="red")
figure, draw = plt.subplots()
Circunferencia = plt.Circle((CoordCirculoX, CoordCirculoY), RadioCirculo, fill=False)
draw.set_aspect(1)
draw.add_artist(Circunferencia)

plt.xlim(-EjeX, EjeX)
plt.ylim(-EjeY, EjeY)
plt.title('Circunferencia')
plt.show()
```

Las gráficas son un circulo y un punto, mi problema es que el código me genera dos gráficas y yo necesito que genere ambas cosas en uno solo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1):

creo que lo que buscas es algo similar a esto

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Circunferencia = plt.Circle((2.5, 2), 2.5, fill=False)

figure, draw = plt.subplots()
draw.set_aspect(1)
draw.cla() # clear to fresh plot

plt.title('Circunferencia')
# Set ranges
draw.set_xlim((-7.5, 7.5))
draw.set_ylim((-8, 8))

# Data comes here
draw.plot(4, 5, marker="o", color="red")
draw.add_patch(Circunferencia)
figure.savefig('Circunferencia')

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo tienes que adaptar el rango del gráfico y posición de cada elemento.
Puedes agregar mas puntos si lo deseas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]